# Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

Having some trouble creating a mysql connection. The mysql instance is running in system preferences and I have made sure the mysql config file is in the right location(Test settings passed). When I go into Test DB connections I get red cross on all three sections.(open database connections, get server version, get server OS). Running mac 10.10.2. Set connection name as home hostname as 127.0.0.1, port as 3306, username as root, password as my computers root password and default schema as home as well. Any ideas?

Comment: mySql password is not the same of your root account. If you didn't provide the root password during the setup, try with an empty password.

Comment: @AndreaGirardi just tried. no luck unfortunately

Comment: which Client you have running - after normal installation there is no password on the database try # mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot

Comment: describe the boxes. is the all on one box, and can you get in to a mysql prompt as root user

Comment: @BerndBuffen MySQL workbench version 6.3.4.

Comment: @Drew which boxes? its the set up new connection box. im not too sure how to get into a mysql prompt as root user. im quite new to this

Comment: have you try it without password

Comment: when I say boxes, I mean, is there only one computer in total, or are you connecting to hostgator, or a server in your basement. It matters

Comment: here is a better client programm for mac http://www.sequelpro.com/

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes Andrea suggested that. Have tried and no luck. Okay will give that program a try

Comment: @Drew only one computer. Been trying to connect to mySQL community server

Comment: is the service running ? try # service mysql status or service mysql start

Comment: get into the mysql/bin directory and run `mysql`, see if it barfs (that is the client program, not the server daemon )... we don't know if mysql daemon is even running (status above comment will tell you)

Comment: @Drew how do i navigate to that directory? Just tried on terminal and it said no such file was found. Sorry Im a newbie with this

Comment: my mac is across town, but I used MAMP bundle so as to make things easier.

Comment: sometimes you have to `sudo` to gain privileges to then get back to root so the `locate` command will work and not error out in certain dirs due to privileges. What I just said probably made no sense to you.

Comment: @Drew sudo /usr/mysql/bin is this the right approach? it came up with command not found though

Comment: do you have a teamviewer session to help you ?

Comment: try # /usr/local/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root

Comment: @BerndBuffen Ive got teamviewer. How did you want me to send you ID and password. just tried the above and command was still not found

Comment: you can send it to buffen@t-online.de - yout teamviewer id and password

Comment: omg teamviewer would be great for this one ! hope you solved it :>

Answer (score 20):

1. Delete pid files using this command:

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/var/mysql
   $ sudo rm -rf [networkname*].err
   $ sudo rm -rf [networkname*].pid
   ```

   2. Now restart server use `brew` sevices

   `$ brew services restart mysql`

*∗your network name like "Tanbirs-Mac-mini.local"
(use `echo $HOST`)*

Comment: You deserve a medal

Comment: Thanks @MikeStardust for your valuable comment , :)

Comment: It is the best answer in the StackOverflow! :)

Comment: @Hayreddin Tüzel Thanks

Comment: just restarting the mysql service did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

You can see this type of error , try this:

run this command on your iTerm or Terminal:

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

If you see some errors like this:

```
my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Starting MySQL

.my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!

my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
```

Just make the dir:

```
mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
```

and then run it again:

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

**Works for me.**

Answer (score 6):

I just had this and the only solution that worked for me was to remove the `ib_logfile*` files from `/usr/local/var/mysql`, similar to Engr.Tanbir Hasan's answer:

```
cd /usr/local/var/mysql
rm ib_logfile*
```

Then restart with (I'm using MariaDB, but same applies to MySQL):

```
brew services restart mariadb
# or
brew services restart mysql
```

I found the solution [here](https://duntuk.com/mariadbmysql-how-fix-unknownunsupported-storage-engine-innodb).

Answer (score 3):

Today i have come with this issue, i solved it using the following steps:

First, check whether listening to the port 3306:

```
netstat -tulpen
```

if it prints the following log, it would be right:

```
...
tcp6 0 0 :::3306 :::* LISTEN 27 46396 22054/mysqld
...
```

otherwise, edit the file `my.cnf` and add the code to it:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

it means that it listens to all ports.

Secondly, in the CentOS 7 add the Mysql service to firewall:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=mysql
```

it returns Success, and then going on executing the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

Now, it's OK!!!

Answer (score 2):

`brew install mysql` worked for me

Then `brew services start mysql`

Comment: The question states that MySQL is already installed and running.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I updated following settings on MAMP/MySQL - Allow Network Access to MySQL to "Only From this Mac" and it fixed the issue for me. I have attached a screenshot here. Also port should be updated to 8889 instead of 3306.
[image: Allow Network Access]

Answer (score 1):

Check your mac version
download the corresponding version
MySQL Community Server (Archived Versions)
8.011 -- 8.031

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but it worked for me.

1. check if you have mysql installed

   [image]

If you don't have mysql installed, download from this link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

2. follow this instructions to install
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html
3. You can test the connection without any problem.

(Sorry for my english, I agree fix me please)

I Hope I've helped.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

The database I use is dependent on DBngin running so this was the error I had.
Close your database management tool and then open the DBngin app and start mysql services. Then when you connect it'll have the database appear to allow you to connect